# How to hide a product category in woocommerce wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hide, product, categories

Just wondered if anyone can help offer some advice on how to hide a category in woocommerce?

I found a snippet of code online to add to my functions file but it unfortunately didn't work, there were syntax errors.

Basically if you visit my homepage below, you can see that we have a christmas category (this appears in the top category carousel).
http://mrsbest.co.uk/

The carousel dynamically displays all categories, there unfortunately isn't a way to specify individual categories.

I don't want to have to delete or uncheck my christmas products so just wondered if there was a way to hide a specific category, then of course I can re-introduce the category next christmas!

This is the code I found which didn't work:

```
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Don't show Categories -
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
add_filter( 'get_terms', 'get_subcategory_terms', 10, 3 );
function get_subcategory_terms( $terms, $taxonomies, $args ) {
 $new_terms = array();
 // if a product category and on the shop page
 if ( in_array( 'product_cat', $taxonomies ) && ! is_admin() ) {
 foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ) {
 if ( ! in_array( $term->slug, array( ‘christmas’ ) ) ) {
 $new_terms[] = $term;
 }
 }
 $terms = $new_terms;
 }
 return $terms;
}
```

Hope you can help!

Many Thanks,

Sarah

Comment: What function are you using to display the categories in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using a theme (nantes) which utlises the OwlCarousel https://github.com/OwlFonk/OwlCarousel.

Although I can work with code, I'm not a developer so don't know the direct answer to your question as I don't know how the carousel integrates with the theme/wordpress but hopes this info helps clarify.

Comment: I'd definitely need to know the actual function being used, in order to help you.

Comment: What was the syntax error and did you try to fix that? If I had to guess I would say the curly quotes around christmas need to be replaced with straight quotes (single or double doesn't matter). Because after fixing that, this code excludes my "testing" category for the product categories widget, so it appears to be working.

Comment: Thanks so much helgatheviking, I change the quote marks around 'christmas' to straight ones and it worked :)